# Why is ArrayAdapter always null in this example?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a code structured as follows:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<User> users;

    private void initAdapter() {
        if(users == null) return;
        //getUserStatus(users); <———HERE 1
        UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(users);
        setListAdapter(users);
        getUserStatus(users);   // vs <—— HERE 2
    }  

    private void getUserStatus(List<User> users) {
        final UsersAdapter  adapter = (UsersAdapter )getListAdapter();
                 for(User user:users) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                //code to fetch some data
                if ( adapter == null) Log.e(“App”, “Adapter is NULL!”);
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }

    private UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public UsersAdapter(List<User> users) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, users);
        }

        @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //code to inflate and populate list item
        }       
    }
```

My question is:
Why if in my `initAdapter` if I comment out `getUserStatus` in the current version marked as `HERE 2` and uncomment `HERE 1` so that `getUserStatus` is run *before* `setListAdapter` the `adapter` is always `null` in `getUserStatus`? I always see in the logs by all threads `Adapter is NULL`?

Comment: `getListAdapter` returns  what you provide by `setListAdapter`

Comment: you need to define or initialise it

Comment: what is `getListAdapter()` is doing, same for setListAdapter().

Comment: For HERE 1 you are getting null adapter because you are initialising and setting adapter after calling `getAdapter` when you havent `setAdapter` then obviously you will get null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. In HERE 1, you are trying to get the user related things from adapter you haven't initialized yet which is inialising using the function setListAdapters(users). In HERE 2, you are getting the users after initialising adapters, so it is working fine.

Comment: But the adapter is accessed *after* "heavy" code (http request) from the background threads. I.e.the part that says `//code to fetch some data` is time consuming.